# PGFPlots Node placement avoid axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, nodes

I have a plot containing a few points and nodes assigned to each coordinate. Upon rendering, some nodes overlap with axes or ticks, which I want to avoid. I've tried using `anchor`, `xshift` (and `yshift`), etc...

How do I style the nodes so they automatically avoid axes and ticks ?

[image]

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Advanced math typesetting
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Plotting

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale=1.5, % Make the plot larger
        title={Points sur le plan complexe}, % Title on top
        xlabel=$Re(z)$, ylabel=$Im(z)$, % Label X and y axes
        xstep=1, ystep=1, % Set the incrementation
        xtick={-2,...,2}, ytick={-2,...,2}, % Incrementation
        axis lines=middle, % Align axes on the center
        enlarge x limits=0.1, enlarge y limits=0.1, % Padding
        axis equal, % Orthogonal
        grid, thick, % Grid options
    ]

        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark=*,
            nodes near coords={\label}, % Use labels
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Label}\as\label}, % Define labels
            every node near coord/.append style={
                font=\large,
                red,
                anchor= north west,
            } % Define label style
        ]
        table[
            x=X, % Read coordinates from table
            y=Y,
            y expr={\thisrow{Y}}, % Make the table read fractions
        ] {coordinates.dat};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`coordinates.dat`

```
Label X   Y
A     0   2
B     1   0
C     1   3/4
D     0   -2
E     -1  0
```

Comment: your `coordinates.dat` is not known ... please complete your code snippet that we can copy and compile it on our computers.

Comment: please help us to help you. compose from codes fragments complete self contained document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document`.

Comment: @Zarko of course, I'm sorry. Edits have been made.

Comment: but your table is still not included ... :-(

Comment: @Zarko table is in the `coordinates.dat` file which I pasted at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not very elegant way is to add an extra column.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{coordinates.dat}
Label X   Y   Yshift
A     0   2   0
B     1   0   20
C     1   3/4 0
D     0   -2  0
E     -1  0   20
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale=1.5, % Make the plot larger
        title={Points sur le plan complexe}, % Title on top
        xlabel=$\mathrm{Re}(z)$, ylabel=$\mathrm{Im}(z)$, % Label X and y axes
        xstep=1, ystep=1, % Set the incrementation
        xtick={-2,...,2}, ytick={-2,...,2}, % Incrementation
        axis lines=middle, % Align axes on the center
        enlarge x limits=0.1, enlarge y limits=0.1, % Padding
        axis equal, % Orthogonal
        grid, thick, % Grid options
    ]

        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark=*,
            nodes near coords={\label}, % Use labels
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Label}\as\label}, % Define labels
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Yshift}\as\myshift}, % Define labels
            every node near coord/.append style={
                font=\large,
                red,
                anchor=north west,
                yshift=\myshift
            } % Define label style
        ]
        table[
            x=X, % Read coordinates from table
%            y=Y, %<- you don't need this
            y expr={\thisrow{Y}}, % Make the table read fractions
        ] {coordinates.dat};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: It is not too difficult to avoid the new column.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{coordinates.dat}
Label X   Y  
A     0   2  
B     1   0  
C     1   3/4
D     0   -2 
E     -1  0  
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale=1.5, % Make the plot larger
        title={Points sur le plan complexe}, % Title on top
        xlabel=$\re z$, ylabel=$\im z$, % Label X and y axes
        xstep=1, ystep=1, % Set the incrementation
        xtick={-2,...,2}, ytick={-2,...,2}, % Incrementation
        axis lines=middle, % Align axes on the center
        enlarge x limits=0.1, enlarge y limits=0.1, % Padding
        axis equal, % Orthogonal
        grid, thick, % Grid options
    ]

        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark=*,
            nodes near coords={\label}, % Use labels
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Label}\as\label}, % Define labels
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Y}\as\myy}, % Define labels
            every node near coord/.append style={
                font=\large,
                red,
                anchor=north west,
                yshift={(1-sign(\myy*\myy))*20}
            } % Define label style
        ]
        table[
            x=X, % Read coordinates from table
%            y=Y, %<- you don't need this
            y expr={\thisrow{Y}}, % Make the table read fractions
        ] {coordinates.dat};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I failed to convince Ti*k*z to change the anchor depending on whether `y=0` or not.

Of course, it would be much better to have a routine that avoids these collisions automatically, but this is far beyond my current skills.

Comment: Well it works for now, I have a small number of points so it's manageable. I'm pretty surprised this isn't as standard yet, but hey. Thanks !

Comment: @ninivert To be honest, I am not an expert. There might be a standard solution, perhaps someone will post it over night...

Comment: I just got started with latex. Aaaand I see you added correct notation for `\mathrm{Re}(z)` as well as the comment for the `y` value, thanks !

Comment: @ninivert I added a solution that does not require an extra column, but this is still far from satisfactory. (And I also added some arguably better macros for the real and imaginary part, the LaTeX built-in commands `\Re` and `\Im` are hard to get used to.)

Comment: Thanks ! Do I still need `\thisrow{Yshift}\as\myshift` ? And could you please explain the `(1-sign(\myy*\myy))*20` part ?

Comment: @ninivert Ooops, I forgot to remove the line. And  `(1-sign(\myy*\myy))*20` is 20 if `\myy` is 0 and 0 otherwise.